# How to collect the node ID on a webform?

Tags: webforms

I have a view showing many products. Each product has its own nid. There is a 'RESERVATION' link in each product as well. When a client clicks on RESERVATION, I want to take him to a form in order for him to provide some more details. Here is my problem, in that form how may I have a hidden field containing the nid of the product on which the client has clicked?

Answer (score 2):

[Re-write](https://drupal.org/node/1578524) the reservation link field to include the ID in the URL.